# jQuery click function not working and button doesn't fadeIn (Laravel)

Tags: jquery, laravel

I want to create rating system (with stars) for every item. Stars would show up only if user hasn't rated the specified item. I've accomplished this by checking in database if user's rating is not null. 
To get the user's rating (number of selected stars), I've created a hidden input field and a submit button which sends this data back to database.
Problem occurs when user presses submit button without checking the stars, and therefore 0 is stored in db. To prevent that I've made a jQuery call to fadeIn the submit button when the rating is made.

Here is my code:

```
            ...
            @foreach($services as $service)
             ...
            @if($service->ratingValue == NULL)
                    <div id="{{$service->id}}" class="rate"></div> //THIS DIV IS PLACE WHERE STARS ARE GENERATED BY ANOTHER JQUERY
                        <input id="input2" type="hidden" name="rateValue">

                        <button style="display:none" id="{{$service->created_at}}" type="submit">OK</button>
                        <script type="text/javascript">

                         $(document).ready(function(){

                          $('#{{$service->id}}').click(function(){
                            $('#{{$service->created_at}}').fadeIn();
                          });
                        });

                      </script>
       @endif
       @endforeach
```

But button does not show up...When I manually enter div's id value as 1 (for example), and button's as 2 (and put it in jQuery) it works. What am I doing wrong here? Or is there a better way to do this? Also I've tried to create an AJAX request to store rating value in db, but it didn't work either.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by doing this: `<button style="display:none"` ? The button won't show by default, unless you change it's style display attribute.

Comment: I want that button to be hidden by default when page is loaded. Also I've tried this: `$("#{{ $service->created_at }}").hide();` and then show it when star is clicked but unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 0):

I think the button style

```
"display:none"..
```

is not needed if you already set the if statement to not show it if the ratingValue is null.